# Editing Ektron frontend page (missing edit bar)

Tags: ektron

I'm using Ektron 9.00. I'm logging into the live frontend site but the bar at the top where i can choose to edited the page is not appearing.

How do I get the bar to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Toolbar" is checked in the Template Configuration. Go to Workarea > Settings > Configuration > Template Configuration. The fourth column in your list of templates is "Enable Toolbar". Make sure that's checked for all templates where you want the toolbar to appear.